# How to filter a dataframe using a cumulative sum of a column as parameter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Mike','Lucy','Mary','Andy'],
                'Age':[10,23,13,12,15],
                '%':[20,20,10,25,25]})
```

I want to filter this df by taking from `row 0 to row n` **until the sum of column % = 50**

I **don't want to sort** the `%` column or the df, I just need to get it's first row where `%` column sums 50

The output is:

```
filtered=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Mike','Lucy'],'Age':[10,23,13],'%':[20,20,10]})
```

Answer (score 1):

cumsum, boolean index and slice using the loc or iloc accessor

```
df.iloc[:(df['%'].cumsum()==50).idxmax()+1,:]



   Name  Age   %
0  John   10  20
1  Mike   23  20
2  Lucy   13  10
```